# IP Restriction Google Cloud Storage

Tags: google-cloud-storage

Is it possible to create a Google Cloud Storage bucket and restrict it's access to one IP?  I plan on using a bucket to store data that only I would ever need to upload/download from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that's not available at this time.

Answer (score 2):

Check out [VPC Service Controls](https://cloud.google.com/vpc-service-controls/).  This no cost feature allows you to restrict client access to project resources based on a variety of attributes, including source IP address, and includes support for Cloud Storage buckets.

Comment: Is there any way to do this without creating a domain to associate the projects to?  See this question.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58811997/service-perimeter-for-project-with-gmail-users

Comment: VPC Service Controls requires a GCP organization.  There is no cost for an organization and it makes managing multiple projects easier as well.  The only prerequisite is an internet domain (or sub-domain) where you can prove ownership as part of the setup process